# At what level does boxing of an object occur in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing

If I have an object such as `List<string>` that I cast into an `object`, and then back again, will all the strings get cast as well or just the list that contains them?

I'm thinking that the compiler would only have to check if the `object` was of type `List<string>` before casting back into a `List<string>` but I grew up in C#, so I'm not entirely certain what goes on behind the code that I write.

Comment: No boxing will be needed at all as long as you are not working directly with a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). Collections of value types *may* result in their contents being boxed (although proper generic classes like `List` will avoid this), but that happens as soon as an item is added to the collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you cast a `List<string>` to an `object`, you're not really doing any casting at all. You're assigning one reference to some data, to a less-specific reference. The `string` objects that it contains aren't changed at all, either.

---

Also, to clarify, there is no boxing involved in this case. Boxing occurs when you create a reference to a value type like an `int` or some `struct`, by assigning it or passing it somehow to a variable of type `object`.

Comment: Add to that that boxing requires a struct - netiher List nor String are structs, they are classes.

Comment: So does this also mean that a `List<object>` would be the same performance wise as a `List<string>` as they are both reference types? Isn't this the reason why generics were created?

Comment: @ChandlerPelhams: Not if you intend to actually *use* it. To use an `object` as a `string`, you need to cast it back again. *That's* one of the reasons generics were created.

Comment: Exactly The <string> saves you a ast when takin a string out. It also wuold save you a boxing operation IF THE PARAMTER WOULD BE A STRUCT - like in <int>. Sadly your example is not a struct (string is not a struct). And you asked for a concrete example.

Answer (score 3):

Boxing occurs when a struct / value type is stored in a location which is typed to object or an interface which that struct implements.  In this scenario both `List<string>` and `string` are reference types so no boxing occurs.

```
struct S1 : IComparable {
  ...
}

S1 local = new S1();  // No box. 
object obj = local;   // Box S1 instance into object
IComparable comp = local;  // Box S1 instance into IComparable
obj = "hello";  // String is a reference type, no boxing
```

Answer (score 2):

`string` is a reference type - an instance of `string` will never get boxed.

If however you had a `List<int>`, the List is a reference type, so there will be no boxing here either. `int` is a value type and it could be boxed IF it were cast to an object (either implicitly or explicitly).

Boxing only affects value types - `List<T>` is a class, hence a reference type, changing the generic type T does not affect whether an instance is passed by value or by reference.

Generic collections help prevent boxing as it enables value types to be read / written without being boxed to an `object`.

Comment: OK, well how about value types? Would there be a need to box a `List<int>`?

Comment: No, because List<int> is a reference type. The CONTENT would not need boxing. int a = list[0] is no boxing, but the the LIST is a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

For every value type, there is a corresponding object type with the same name which is derived from ValueType.  Whenever it is necessary to create a storage location (field, variable, or parameter) of a given type, the system will allocate space to store either a heap reference (if the type does not derive from ValueType), all of the type's fields (if it's a 'struct'), or the bits holding the types value.  Boxing occurs when an attempt is made to store an instance of a value type into a heap reference.  Unboxing occurs when an attempt is made to use a heap reference as though it were a value type.  Note that in some contexts, unboxing will copy the contents of boxed object to a new storage location, but in other contexts it will regard the boxed instance as a storage location.  The semantics of this are not always clear, which is one of the reasons some people hate mutable structs.  In practice, mutable structs are fine if one avoids usage scenarios where the semantics get murky, and even immutable structs can suffer from the same murky semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `List<string>` will be casted.

If you want to cast the `List<string>` items do this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"first", "second"};
List<object> objectsList = list.Cast<object>();
```

P.S. `string` is a reference type so it can't really get `boxed` and `unboxed`

Answer (score 0):

Boxing and Unboxing is the actions that applies to Value Types not to Reference Types.

It's not that, it's just a simple cast.